# Accessing Properties of Base class from derived class using Generic List

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, generics

In C#, was is the best way to access a property of the Base class when the generic list contains  derived  class.

```
public BaseClass1
{
  public Property A{get;set;}
   public Property B{get;set;}
}
 public BaseClass2:BaseClass1
{
   public Property C{get;set;}
   public Property D{get;set;}
}
public classA:BaseClass2
{
}

public class Implement
  {
    List<classA> list1 = new List<classA>()

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add another person");//If yes I would like add person to the list dynamically

    {
        //Is it possible to acesses properties of Baseclass using derived class List
       List1.Property A = Console.readline();//read input from console
       List1.Property B = Console.readline();//read input from console
           .
           .
       List.Property D = Console.readline();//read input from console

       List1.add(Property A,Property B);//add properties of baseclass1 and baseclass2 as well as derived class 

    }
   }
```

I want to take values of base class properties from the console and add those values to the List and increase the list if the user wants to add more objects of classA.
Is this possible??

Comment: You can access the properties of the base class, yes, but you have to construct a new object of type "classA", and add that to the list. The list does not magically get all the properties of the type it contains.

Answer (score 1):

```
List1.Add( new ClassA { A = a, B = b, C = c } );
```